# VSCode HTML "pieces"

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I use "pieces" to avoid confusion with the built-in "snippets" functionality.

The scenario is that I am rendering pages server-side in Nodejs, and as part of that I want to code portions of html in files that can be used to assemble an entire page. These are project-specific so the snippets functionality is really not useful here. Problem is if I write an html file that for example only has a  section, VSCode tells me there is an error since that file does not start with <DOCTYPE>, etc.

The goal here is reusable pieces instead of duplicating for each page. E.g. define a header.html file that only defines the <header> section, and can then be inserted into each rendered page.

Has anyone done similar? How to tell VSCode to treat as HTML but without demanding a complete document and indicating an error?

Comment: you can look at the Django extension